# Magento Clears Session Data After Redirect

Tags: magento-1, customer-account, session, register, customer-session

For some reason, magento clears session or customer session data after redirect? How will I save some data before it redirect to the next page into a session?

I tried adding `session_write_close();` but this doesn't help.

**Update:**

Some actions do not retrieve `Magento::getSingleton('core/session')` whole data.

Comment: This then means your customer gets logged out after the redirect, which would be poor user experience. Rather than doing a workaround, saving the session data, it would be best to figure out why the session is clearing. Is there, by any chance, a 404 happening in the redirect (not the redirect itself, but some resource (be it image/css/js) on the redirected location? See this post: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/385/cart-dropping-all-items-cart-session-clears - it may contain some helpful information

Answer (score 0):

If session not totaly clears, you can try this:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));  //load session variables
$session->setData("data", $data); //save your data in custom session variable
```

And then, when you need this data:

```
$data = $session->getData("data"); //get data from custom variable
```