# No items in cart message when place something in cart on my website

Tags: cart

When I add a product into checkout, then I go to my checkout there's any empty cart.

My cookie limit is 86400, which I believe is more than enough

What could cause this? Many Thanks

Comment: I believe this could be something to do with the website being https as I have another website on the same magento which is only http which works fine. Does anyone have any ideas, thanks so much?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your cart/checkout session is dropping. Why? That is the 10 million dollar question.

There can be a multitude of reasons.
You will need to debug this, and try to determine when, at what point the session drops/is renewed. If the session is dropped/renewed,you will get a new quote object, thus a blank brand new empty cart.

Unfortunately this issue is to broad to debug with such little information.

You will need to investigate, and place your findings as you go along, and hope something you find will enable someone to help you.

Please see this post: [Cart dropping all items / cart session clears](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/385/cart-dropping-all-items-cart-session-clears)

Here I, myself had a similar issue.
I describe some items I had tried, so that will help you with ideas of what to try.

It is a largish post, but to sum it up: Cart session were dropped by "behind the scene" 404's on completely unrelated page elements, which failed to load, due to some files on server being missing. These were images. So, something as trivial as a 404, dropped the session, thus dropped the cart. just but one possible reason.

Good luck. These are a paid to track down.

Comment: I believe this could be something to do with the website being https as I have another website on the same magento which is only http which works fine. Does anyone have any ideas, thanks so much?