# customers cant login magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login

I was certain we tested all of this prior to going live but customers are unable to login using the "my account" link or from the checkout page.  The "log in" link seems to work but nothing will stay in the cart.

I can still checkout as guest.  I found many posts about adding the form-key.  I used developer debug to find my login.phtml on my "my account" page.  Added the string and cleared cache.  Users still cant login.  Anyone have any ideas or point me in the right direction?

I recently moved the site to SSL...I have tried changing it back to standard and that does not fix it either.

I also tried turning off persistent cart and that did not fix it.  This issue seemed to come about after enabling persistent cart.

I also noticed that if you click the forgot password option and enter an email address of a valid users it just returns you to the page and says "please enter your email"

Comment: I tried this as well with no luck.

Do the following:

    Go to System > Configuration > Web
    Expand Session Cookie Management
    Set the following:
    Cookie Path: /
    Cookie Domain: yoursite.com
    Use HTTP Only: No

Comment: I found one recommendation that suggested setting the permissions on /var to 777....is this recommended?

Comment: `var/` should be restricted by .htaccess from being viewable on the frontend, so permission should be lax.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/385/cart-dropping-all-items-cart-session-clears  check for errant 404s happening via the network tab in browser to images. If server not correctly setup this could cause sessions to be recreated.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `System > Configuration > Web` Expand `Session Cookie Managemen`t Set the following: `Cookie Path: / Cookie Domain: yoursite.com Use HTTP Only: Yes.` Got to `var/sessions` and clear folder.Try again...you should be ok.